# Polynomial Class runs fine in debugger but not when trying to build&run

Tags: c++, class, debugging

So I've been trying to solve this problem for some hours but without any succes. I've got a class for Polynomial methods(set/get grade, set/get polynom's coefficients, print polynom, find every y = f(x) for a given set of numbers etc.)

However, the problem is that whenever the grade of the polynom is even, the build&run returns strange values. The debug of it runs prefectly fine. On the other side, whenever the grade is uneven, works perfectly fine for both debug and build&run. I'm thinking the problem is somewhere at dinamically allocated memory. Here's the code. Thanks

main.cpp

```
    #include "poly_header.h"


int main()
{
    Poly p;
    p.AfisareValori();

    return 0;
}
```

poly_header.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;


class Poly
{
private:
    int grad;
    int* coeficienti;
    int a;
    int b;
    int dx;
public:
    Poly();
    void SetGrad();
    int GetGrad();
    void SetCoef();
    void GetCoef();
    void SetPolyn();
    void PrintPoly();
    void SetInterval();
    void SetDistanta();
    void AfisareValori();
    ~Poly();
};
```

poly_functions.cpp

```
#include "poly_header.h"

Poly::Poly()
{
    this->grad = 0;
    this->coeficienti = new int[0];
}

Poly::~Poly()
{
    delete coeficienti;
}

void Poly::SetGrad()
{
    int n;
    cout<<"Introduceti gradul dorit al polinomului: ";
    cin>>n;
    this->grad = n;
}

int Poly::GetGrad()
{
    cout<<"\n";
    return this->grad;
}

void Poly::SetCoef()
{
    int n;
    this->coeficienti = new int[this->grad];
    for(int i = 0; i <= this->grad; i++){
        cout<<"Introduceti coeficientul "<<i<<" :";
        cin>>this->coeficienti[i];
        cout<<"\n";
    }
}

void Poly::GetCoef()
{
    cout<<"\n";
    for(int i = 0; i <= this->grad; i++)
        cout<<"Coeficientul asociat termenului x^"<<i<<" este:"<<this->coeficienti[i]<<"\n";
}

void Poly::SetPolyn()
{
    SetGrad();
    SetCoef();
}

void Poly::PrintPoly()
{
    SetPolyn();
    for(int i = grad; i >= 0; i--){
        if(i == 0){
            cout<<coeficienti[i];
            break;
        }
        cout<<coeficienti[i]<<"*X^"<<i<<" + ";
    }
}

void Poly::SetInterval()
{
    int a,b;
    cout<<"Introduceti capatul din stanga al intervalului: ";
    cin>>a;
    this->a = a;
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"Introduceti capatul din dreapta al intervalului: ";
    cin>>b;
    this->b = b;
    cout<<"\n";
}

void Poly::SetDistanta()
{
    int dx;
    cout<<"Introduceti distanta dintre puncte: ";
    cin>>dx;
    this->dx = dx;
    cout<<"\n";
}

void Poly::AfisareValori()
{
    SetPolyn();
    SetInterval();
    SetDistanta();
    int suma;
    for(int i = a; i <= b; i+=dx){
        suma = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j <= grad; j++){
            suma += coeficienti[j] * (pow (i,j));
        }
        cout<<"Valorea polinomului in punctul "<<i<<" este "<<suma<<"\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: You would have similar problems even without dynamic allocation - the greatest valid index in `coeficienti` is `grad - 1`.

Comment: It also works with 3, 5, 7. It`s tested..

Comment: In the last loop (the one with `j <= grad`) you are accessing `coefficienti[grad]` which does not exist, because you allocated via `new int[this->grad];`. It is not surprising, that this crashes, what is surprising is that you claim that it works in some cases. Are you really sure, that your test is ok?

Comment: Indexing outside the allocated memory is undefined. It only appears to work in the odd cases, and the results are a coincidence.

Comment: You have a polynomial of degree `grad - 1`. You need to allocate one more coefficient. (A polynomial of degree `g` has `g + 1` coefficients.)

Comment: completely aside your actual problem, I would advice to do not mix the input from the user inside your class. It is a violation of the SRP (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Also, unit test your code and you will spot this kind or error almost immediately.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers. 
decltype_auto made it pretty clear for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A polynomial P of degree ('grad' by your wording) N has N+1 coefficients;

In pseudo code:

```
length((N, N-1, ... 1, 0)) = N + 1.
```

thus this

> ```
> void Poly::SetCoef()
> {
>     /*...*/ 
>     this->coeficienti = new int[this->grad];
>     /*...*/ 
> )
> ```

allocates one int too less.

Polynomials of even degree have an odd number N of coefficients, Polynomials of odd degree have an even number of coefficients.

I you allocate an `int` too less, the bucket too less for the polynomials of odd degree is at an boundary of a 2*sizeof(int) memory alignment; thus, it is likely that that bucket is not used otherwise.

This doesn't hold for even degrees, their missing bucket is within a new alignment block.

That's also the explanation for the discrepancy between debug and release mimics; the debug compiler run simply packs the memory less dense than the release compiler.

Besides that, you don't have to deal with manual field allocation at all for your purpose; e.g. [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [`std::valarray`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray) automate that task in safe manner.

Comment: Thank you for this complete answer. It finally worked and I got the idea behind it.

Comment: yw, please keep in mind to look for std::vector and std::valarray. For a once runtime-sized, but subsequently size-fixed real or complex coefficient sequence of type `T` and `grad+1` length , a` std::valarray<T> coeficienti_(T(0.), grad+1)`   is a solid choice.